# How should a container give access to groupadd without sudo?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am attempting to use an image in an Azure DevOps pipeline but that image doesn't meet [the following requirement of Linux-based containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#:%7E:text=USER%20has%20access%20to%20groupadd%20and%20other%20privileges%20commands%20without%20sudo):

> `USER` has access to `groupadd` and other privileges commands without `sudo`

Because of this, Azure fails to inject its bits and pieces because that ability isn't available, and the pipeline fails.

This isn't something I've intentionally done to the image. How would I go about permitting the user to access `groupadd` etc without needing `sudo`?

Comment: what kind of Docker image you are using in your yaml file and at which step you are facing the issue? also, can u share logs of the failed task?

Comment: Note that I also faced docker permission issues after setting up a self-hosted Azure DevOps build agent and installing docker. The next day the issue was gone. So either the restart or the logging out from the agent was the key success factor.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer would be running the image as root. Which is not safe at all.
Another answer, or more exactly, a workaround, has been given by [Josh Channings](https://github.com/joshchngs) on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/4332). In your Dockerfile, you should have...

```bash
...
chmod u+s /usr/sbin/groupadd /usr/sbin/usermod && \
touch /etc/sudoers && \
chmod u+w /etc/sudoers && \
rm -f /bin/su && \
echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' > /bin/su && \
echo "echo 'su' has been disabled in this container" >> /bin/su && \
chmod +x /bin/su && \
...
```

Basically, we overwrite **/bin/su** and update permissions so that we can use **groupadd** and **usermod**. This is not convenient at all, but it works. The answer also covers the case where **/etc/sudoers** does not exist in the base image.